# Is there a connection between the MVC model and the Bridge design pattern?

Tags: design-patterns, model-view-controller

I tried looking into the **Bridge** design pattern, and stumbled upon various answers online. Eventually, I think I got the hang of it. Feel free to correct me if I'm wrong about this, but I could use the Bridge pattern to separate specific data from how to render that specific data.

When I came to that understanding, it struck me that I'm already familiar with something of the same nature, the MVC model, where it states that we have a model (data), and a view (UI to render) and a controller that queries the model in favor of the view.

So is there a correlation between the two things or is it just me getting confused with the Bridge pattern? If there is more to the Bridge pattern please let me know.

Comment: Model-View-Controller is mostly an exercise in *Separation of Concerns.*  A "Bridge Pattern" is something else, mostly having to do with *specifying impementations at runtime.*  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bridge_pattern and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns

Answer (score 1):

Bridge is a general purpose pattern that extends how we usually implement polymorphism.
For example, consider the canonical example of drawing shapes.

```
Abstract Class Shape(
    abstract function draw();
)

Class Circle extends Shape(
    draw(){ /*draw a circle*/}
)

Class Square extends Shape(
    draw(){ /*draw a square*/}
)
```

Now we can make an array of shapes (cosnsisting of squares and circles ) and tell each object in the array to draw itself using shape->draw() on each element. (all pseudo code)

Now suppose the way to draw circles and squares are different on different systems. We could add new  abstract draw() frunction like drawWindows() and drawXwin() with the corresponding implementations.

Alternatively we can use Bridge and pass in an object that implements the drawAPI ( and we can have many concrete subclasses that draw differently.

```
Abstract Class Shape(
    protected drawAPI;         // object that implements drawAPI

    abstract function draw();

    Shape( drawAPIin){  // constructor
     drawAPI =  drawAPIin;
    }
)

Class Circle extends Shape(

    draw(){ drawAPI->draw();}
)

Class Square extends Shape(
    draw(){ drawAPI->draw();}
)
```

Now we can still make an array of shapes (cosnsisting of squares and circles ) and tell each object in the array to draw itself using shape->draw() on each element but this time will draw() according to the draw() of the drawAPI object passed to the constructor of Shape (get it? :-) ). Anyhow is a very flexible approach.

Contract this to MVC which is a specialised pattern used most commonly to separate the concerns of data storage/retrieval(Model's function), data display and user input (View's functions) and marshalling that data between the Model and the View (Controller's function). There are several variations of the MVC pattern, as can be seen in various front-end and back-end web dev frameworks.

As you can see, the intent of Bridge Pattern and MVC are quite different, although as you point out there may be points of overlap. While its probably not entirely correct to consider them as different names for the same pattern, there are connections as you point out, in the same way that most of the GoF patterns overlap and are connected in many ways.

As we raise the abstraction level in thinking about problems, ideas and solutions often seem to merge and look similar. But the devil and the payoff is in the detail and a good place to start is to look closely at the **intent** of every pattern to understand their differences.